# Patents and Dependent Claims

Tags: infringement, independent, dependent-claim, changing, variation

I am from the UK, just looking for a pretty simple answer as I have been spending abit more time looking at patents now than ever before.

So, I understand independent claims are broad. Then you have dependent claims. Currently I am working against a patent with dependent claims. What I am trying to understand is, if I invalidate a dependent claim, but not the original claim then:

1. Can this be possible?
2. If it is, then is it infringement?
3. If for example the initial claim mentions 3 parts in this manner:

"a flexible structure with three specific, clearly differentiated areas of a different nature"

but I reduce it to 2 parts whilst keeping the like for like functionality, is this infringement?

Thank you all, i have spent the whole day racking my brains!

Answer (score 4):

An independent claim will always encompass all of its dependent claims. That means that something infringing a dependent claim will always infringe the independent claim too. A dependent claim is just a narrow version of the independent claim.

So let's imagine you would invalidate a dependent claim, e.g. a+b+c. Then your abc would still infringe the independent a+b claim. Because a+b means a+b+ anything (x). And that's the catch. Abc is prior art for ab+x and can invalidate the ab claim.

It it's impossible to invalidate a claim that only specifies a broader claim without invalidating the broader claim. Dependent claims exist for a similar case. Because abd would invalidate ab, abc is used as a fallback position.

There is one exception that's actually not an exception but could lead to confusion. If in the past abc was thought to be impossible without a and b and c you can invent ac. By the above logic that would mean that abc infringes your ac claim. But that's just a limitation of this simple example structure. Ac in this case is actually abc-b or only ac“.

If you tried to make abc a dependent claim because it's more narrow than ac, that wouldnt work because abc-b+b doesn't make sense and neither does “only ac“ + b.

To summarise, any protection that a dependent claim grants may not be broader than the protection the independent claim grants. And an example of prior art that falls into the protection of a claim is enough for invalidation, so by definition invalidating a dependent claim must invalidate the independent claim.

---

> "a flexible structure with three specific, clearly differentiated areas of a different nature"
>
> but I reduce it to 2 parts whilst keeping the like for like functionality, is this infringement?

If the claim clearly states that the parts have to be present then no, **unless** you're running into equivalency. That's basically infringing by substituting a part of the claim without functional differences. But that's a different, very complex topic. I just mention it because shipping around the wording of a claim without shipping around the meaning will get you into problems with that.

Comment: Damn this is good!